# I'm replacing numbers from a text file with asterisks. How can I get my C++ program to print more than one line?

Tags: c++

So upon user input of 3, the following should execute;

```
        else if (a == 3) {
            // Use Python to create the frequency.dat file and then read from it
            CallProcedure("Frequency");
            ifstream inFile("frequency.dat");
            while (inFile >> itemName >> itemQuantity) {
                cout << itemName << " ";
            // Replace the item quantity with an asterisk character
                for (int i = 0; i < itemQuantity; i++) {
                cout << "*";
                }
                cout << endl;
                inFile.close();
                system("pause");
                break;
            }
        }
```

The goal is for it to take information from this frequency.dat file, which is formatted in the following format;

```
Apples 4
Beets 3
```

And then convert the numbers to asterisks, with the same character count.
So for example;

```
Apples ****
Beets ***
```

The problem is that my program will only print the first line. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: After handling first line you close the file stream, pause then break the loop. Of course it only prints the first line.

Comment: Apologies, Julien. I'm still learning C++ and Python implementation so I typed Python by mistake. And thank you @MarkSouls I can't believe I didn't notice that. Got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking out of your while loop :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I realized my mistake thanks to MarkSouls comment about my program closing the file stream, pausing, and breaking the loop. I removed these portions out of my code and it works as intended.